# How does Node.js effectively manage the event loop and task association for incoming requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, operating-system

I have a question regarding operating system with server node

When the request is sent to our HTTP server

First question: Is this request for a new connection or a new process or a new thread?

Second question: The event loop is for managing asynchronous tasks, how can it find out which request this performed task is related to?

I mean if a lot of requests are sent

How the result of these requests is sent to each of them
I think there should be a part to map the ID of each new request with its task in the JavaScript engine

I expect somewhere in the operating system or somewhere in javascript

Specify the performed tasks related to which request with which ID

Comment: Your querstion is more of a discussion and less of a question

Comment: so event loop is a process for running tasks, but nodejs need to add those tasks to event loop that happens through libraries like express or http in nodejs.

Comment: what does `which request with which ID` even mean? do requests have an ID? why do you think they do? where does the ID come from? what does the ID mean?

Comment: "*The event loop is for managing asynchronous tasks, how can it find out which request this performed task is related to?*" wait ***WHY*** would *you* have to find this out? The event loop is just the internal mechanism of how tasks are processed. You normally never need to interact with it as if it's a loop. Write your code to work with some data and that's it. You don't have to somehow match the data to the async task yourself.

Comment: I know all the things you said - I know the function of the event loop, but my question is something else
Actually my question is when we have a lot of requests and all of them are added and executed in the event loop according to the order
How JavaScript determines which task corresponds to which request

@VLAZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an incoming request arrives at your server, it is fielded by a listening object at the OS level (in the TCP stack).  So, at the OS level, that results in the creation of a new socket which represents a bi-directional TCP connection between client and server.  That socket is essentially the ID that identifies a particular connection between two endpoints.

Meanwhile, the listening object in the nodejs process gets notified that there's a new connection on its http server.  This goes through the nodejs event queue where a particular phase of the event queue checks for these incoming notifications and, if found, then calls a Javascript callback listener for that notification.  At this point, it's just running normal Javascript within nodejs.

> First question: Is this request for a new connection or a new process or a new thread?

The initial part of creating the new connection is done within the OS and it's really up to the OS how it does that.  It likely uses some threads within the OS (inside the TCP stack), but no new thread is created for each incoming connection.

Then, the incoming connection is processed by a particular phase of the nodejs event loop which does not use a new thread and does not create a thread for the incoming connection.  The incoming connection is just processed by the normal operation of the nodejs event loop and the Javascript callback it calls to process this event from the event loop is just a normal Javascript callback running in the single Javascript thread of the interpreter.

> Second question: The event loop is for managing asynchronous tasks, how can it find out which request this performed task is related to?

The network stack in the OS creates a socket object that uniquely identifies a specific connection between two endpoints.  The TCP library within nodejs uses that socket object.  It gets wrapped into a nodejs socket object which the HTTP library uses.  When traffic arrives on that socket or is sent to that socket, it uses the TCP socket object as the identifier so the underlying TCP stack knows which endpoint to send the data to or which endpoint incoming data came from.

> How the result of these requests is sent to each of them
> I think there should be a part to map the ID of each new request with its task in the JavaScript engine

The TCP stack in the OS knows how to use the socket object that it created to know which endpoints that socket belongs to, what state the connection is in, what settings it has, what traffic is buffered for it, etc...

> I expect somewhere in the operating system or somewhere in javascript

In the native code in the TCP stack in the OS.